# If a flight ticket indicates that the maximum luggage weight is "50 lb/23kg", is the limit 50lb or 23kg?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, fees-and-charges, qatar-airways, sfo

23kg = 50.7 lb. I know that typically the check-in counter agents would allow check-in luggage to be above 1 lb the maximum free authorized weight, but just in case some agent decides to strictly apply the luggage weight policy.

[image]

If specific to the airline, I'm currently interested in Qatar Airways. If specific to the departure airport, I'm currently interested in SFO.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure just pick the lower limit.

Comment: @jcm true but I'd prefer to know the actual policy to make sure that I don't unnecessarily restrict myself.

Comment: First and foremost these limits are so that baggage handlers don't injure themselves lifting your luggage.  The fact that there's a 23 kg limit doesn't mean you have to overload your suitcase until you hit 23 kg.

Comment: @Kyralessa actually the nonfree limit for my ticket is 32kg. The 23kg/50lb limit is $$$ for airline.

Comment: My guess is that for countries that follow metric system Kg limit is followed & for countries that follow the imperial system, lb limit is followed. So check-in agent will follow whatever scale the weighing machine uses unless it returns values in both scales in which case you should be okay if either of values are within limits. If you are really splitting hairs your nonfree limit is actually 70lb/32kg per your comment.

Comment: I wouldn't assume the scale (yours or at the airport) will always be that precisely calibrated (you are talking about a 320 g difference). Note that 23kg is indeed close to the recommended limits for handling (it also depend on the body position, height, and specific movements you have to do; if you are doing it all day the limits per item are lower). *In theory*, safely handling 32 kg requires two people or handling equipement (which would justify charging for it).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sure, but the more people who pay for 32kg instead of 23kg, the more baggage handlers are needed and the more effect it's going to have on their health.  If you've ever paid for a bag heavier than 23kg, you've surely noticed that the check-in agent puts a bright label on it indicating that it's overweight.  There's a reason for that.  Even if the charges are merely punitive and not directed toward a specific purpose, it makes sense from a personnel perspective to discourage people from overloading the baggage handlers.

Comment: I second relaxed here. The scales used at check-in are not accurate and many even show different weights depending on where on the 'platform' you put your bag. I had an argument with an airline a few years ago as they wanted to charge 2kg overweight for a bag, which was definitely below the limit when I checked at home before leaving and after some discussion, they cockily offered me to try a different scale just to prove that they have accurate scales and voila, the two scales showed more than 3kg difference.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo true but regardless of the scale accuracy, it'd be nice to know what's the upper bound if strictly applying the policy

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The 32kg is a much harder limit than the 23kg. The 32kg limit is there to protect workers, it is deemed the maximum weight they can handle. That one is in my experience enforced a lot more strictly. But as other have said, they will use the weight as shown on the scale, so in pounds in the US and in kg elsewhere.

Comment: @jcaron Any source for that? It's a bit more complicated than a simple threshold but 23 kg seems much more relevant than 32 kg from a worker health and safety perspective. For example, the safe “load constant“ is in the NIOSH lifting equation is 50 lbs (and that's for someone who is standing, using both hands, etc. it only goes down when you add constraints and still isn't deemed safe for 25% of women). Other norms have slightly different approaches but broadly similar results.

Comment: @Relaxed, that is why weight limits in work have gone down over the years and why luggage weights may go down in the future.

Comment: @Willeke Sure but that's not completely new (the revision of the NIOSH lifting equation dates from 1991) and hard to justify today. Even military norms have lower limits than this! You can only maintain 32 kg as a limit with some pretense of putting special procedures in place (hence the marking). Consequently, I still find the notion that the 32 kg limit is currently seen as a hard limit to protect workers whereas the 23 kg doesn't matter from this perspective highly questionable and I am curious to know where that idea is coming from.

Comment: [Where does the 23kg/32kg typical limit for checked in luggage for international flights come from?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162865/1810) in case comments get removed. Afaic, we should automate airports much more. Most of baggage handling can be automated.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Large parts of it are already automated in some airports but typically automation doesn't remove the need for human operators, it only creates new, often harder tasks for them.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience airlines almost never enforce these limits that precisely.  I've been allowed to check bags weighing a little more than the limit on several occasions.

When they do enforce the limit precisely, they use the units of measurement that prevail in the place where you are checking in.  I have been held strictly to the limit on only two or three occasions.  The limit was 50 lbs in the US and 23 kilos everywhere else, notably including the UK.

Comment: They are usually a bit flexible on the 50 lb/23 kg limit, though much less on the 70 lb/32 kg max (as this one is a hard limit to protect workers). Low-cost airlines which have a much finer granularity (e.g. Easyjet has 3 kg steps IIRC) may also be a bit more strict.

Comment: @jcaron my most memorable experience was with Norwegian Air Shuttle in London, where the limit in question was for the carry-on, from which I removed one sweater after another, put it on, and re-weighed the bag, until finally they gave up and let me take it without charging (and before I had it under the limit).  This was not an entirely disingenuous exercise because I was actually planning on wearing all of these layers on the plane because I had been desperately cold on the outward journey.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience they look the weight in the scale, which it is not so precise and it has just one unit. SFO: I expect they will have lb-only scales, and so they would check just this number. I'm not sure they can convert easily the weights.

The only problem arrise if you have a domestic flight later (and possibly to a domestic only airport), in a metric country. In this case you may pass custom with your baggage and check it again. Arguing with transfer desk is not always the best way to pass time with a short connection. OTOH it should not matter: the rule of the longest flight should be applied on checked baggage.